# Black screen when embedding .mov video on my website

Tags: html, html5-video, mov

So I'm trying to embed a `.mov` video to a website with the following:

```
<video src="myvideo.mov" controls></video>
```

the video when played shows a black screen and all I hear is the audio.

Tried with several videos with same  `.mov` extension but nothing works, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see the video because, in `HTML 5`, there are only 3 video types that are supported:

1. .mp4
2. .webM
3. .ogg

If you want the video to be shown, you need either of the video type.

What you can do is:

1. Change the current video type to the either of above video type

Once done, you can then update your code to this:

```
<video src="path/to/video-file.mp4" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

For more information on video element, refer [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and  [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)